# Update/Write lines content

Tags: tcl

How to update/write as belows;

1.First case: I want to update/replace new content in line 4 only with content format at line 4 like this:  `none;none;C:\data\update\text.txt;onfiles` format at line 4

change index 2 become `C:\data\update\new\newtext.txt`

2.Second case: how to write/replace a contents from line 3 until end.

```
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    incr count
    if {$count <= 2} {
        puts $fp $line ;#write old content
    } elseif {$count == 3} { ;#update line 3 only with parameter below
         if {not match/different content} {
             #update/write...
         } else {
             #do not write or skip write (still use old content)
         }
    } else {
        #new content/update...
            #...
            #...
            #...
            #until end what i need
    }
}
```

Comment: Please go thru with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
set data {
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;mydata;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
}

set lines [split [string trim $data] \n]

# replace one field
lset lines 2 [join [lreplace [split [lindex $lines 2] \;] 1 1 HELLO] \;]

# replace three rows
set n 0
for {set i 3} {$i < [llength $lines]} {incr i} {
    incr n
    lset lines $i "test$n;test$n;test$n"
}

# remove one row
set lines [lrange $lines 0 5]

puts [join $lines \n]
```

In this case, the steps "replace three rows" and "remove one row" could also be done this way:

```
set lines [lrange $lines 0 2]
set n 0
while {$n < 3} {
    lappend lines "test[incr n];test$n;test$n"
}
```

This line is a little dense:

```
lset lines 2 [join [lreplace [split [lindex $lines 2] \;] 1 1 HELLO] \;]
```

It works like this:

```
set line [lindex $lines 2]
set fields [split $line \;]
set fields [lreplace $fields 1 1 HELLO]
set line [join $fields \;]
lset lines 2 $line
```

Documentation:
[< (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm),
[lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm),
[lreplace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.htm),
[lset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
set input {data;data;data
data;data;data
data;mydata;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;data;data}

puts Input
puts [string repeat - 40]
puts $input
puts [string repeat - 40]
set lines [split $input \n]
set lineToChange [lindex $lines 2]
set updatedLine [join [lreplace [split $lineToChange ";"] 1 1 HELLO] ";"]
set output [join [lreplace $lines 2 2 $updatedLine] \n]
puts Output
puts [string repeat - 40]
puts $output
```

**Execution results:**

```
Input
----------------------------------------
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;mydata;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
----------------------------------------
Output
----------------------------------------
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;HELLO;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
data;data;data
----------------------------------------
```